# Extending Prism NavigationParameters with a title

Tags: c#, navigation, prism

I'm trying to achieve a navigation journal which has, along with the uri and the parameters of the navigation, a string containing some info created at the time of requesting the navigation:

```
public class ExtendedNavigationParameters : NavigationParameters
{
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
}
```

So, when I want to navigate to some specific object, I want to pass some title along with the Uri and the Parameters collection, so I set that property in my extended parameters object:

```
 ExtendedNavigationParameters parameters = new ExtendedNavigationParameters { {"Maquina", Maquina}};
 parameters.Titulo = Maquina.Descripcion;
```

Then this parameters are sent through the `RequestNavigate` method:

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(IdRegion, Uri, parameters);
```

At that point, the parameters object is of type `ExtendedNavigationParameters`. However, after navigation is completed, when I try to access this info trough  `RegionNavigationJournal.CurrentEntry.Parameters`the object is of type `NavigationParameters` (exception trying to cast to `ExtendedNavigationParameters`).

Why is this? Is the object recreated at some point? How can I store that info in the `RegionNavigationJournal`?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea. Why extend `NavigationParameters`? You can add any object into the parameters collection as a name/value pair. Either make the name the title you want, or add a Title to the value object, or use a tuple, or a special object you use for passing the title and object as one complex object.

Comment: @R.Richards, didn't really rhought of that. It would work for me. Elaborate as an answer and I'll set it as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to this that would work versus extending `NavigationParameters`.

The first is to use a Tuple to pass the information.

```
private void DoNavigation()
{
    var parameters = new NavigationParameters();
    var paramPayload = new Tuple<string, Maquina>("Maquina", _maquina);
    parameters.Add("Payload", paramPayload);
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate(IdRegion, Uri, parameters);
}
```

In the Tuple object (`paramPayload`), the Item1 property would point to the title, Item2 property would point to the object of interest. `_maquina` holds a reference to the object you are try to send during navigation. How that gets created, I will let you take care of.

The other approach that would work is to create a object that would package up the information into one unit to pass.

The class for this object could look like this:

```
public class NavigationPayload
{
    public NavigationPayload(string title, object payload)
    {
        Title = title;
        Payload = payload;
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public object Payload { get; set; }
}
```

To use it:

```
private void DoNavigation()
{
    var parameters = new NavigationParameters();
    var paramPayload = new NavigationPayload("Maquina", _maquina);
    parameters.Add("Payload", paramPayload);
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate(IdRegion, Uri, parameters);
}
```

Whether you use the Tuple, or an object of your own design, is entirely up to you.

Some programmers tend to use Tuple only for prototyping, and move to a custom object for final implementation, because intent is a little more clear. But, there is no hard and fast rule there.

Good luck to you!